# How to efficiently sample a volume in numpy?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a 3D boolean array in numpy.  I would like to pick a random element out of those that have a `True` value (if any).  The probability of picking any `True` element should be the same.  I need the coordinates of the selected element.

Methods that work but aren't especially fast:

- picking elements at random and checking if they are True
- forming a list of the indexes of all True elements (for example with `numpy.nonzero`) and then picking at random from that

The array is typically a cube with size 256x256x256.  True elements are around 1% to 10% of the total number.

Comment: Hmm, aren't those two bullets the only ways to possibly generate a result?

Comment: @Paul Maybe...  Indexed or non-indexed would seem to be the two main approaches, but non-indexed could be vectorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your approaches can be bettered in a principal manner. Anyway, here is a `flatnonzero` solution and a trial-and-error one for comparison:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def pick_true(data, n):
    nz = np.flatnonzero(data)
    return np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(nz, n), data.shape)


def pick_true_2(data, n, p):
    pick = np.random.randint(0, data.size, (int(round(n/p)),))
    return np.unravel_index(pick[data.ravel()[pick]], data.shape)

data = np.random.random((256,256,256)) < 0.01

print(pick_true(data, 10), data[pick_true(data, 10)])

print('indexing small {:6.4f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: pick_true(data, 100), number=10)/10))
print('indexing large {:6.4f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: pick_true(data, 10000), number=10)/10))


print(pick_true_2(data, 10, 0.01), data[pick_true_2(data, 10, 0.01)])

print('non-indexing small {:6.4f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: pick_true_2(data, 100, 0.01), number=10)/10))
print('non-indexing large {:6.4f} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: pick_true_2(data, 10000, 0.01), number=10)/10))
```

sample output:

```
(array([  8, 164, 247, 160, 154, 147, 146,  73,  89,   1]),
array([ 89,   0,   7, 217,  46,  45, 139, 205, 163,  92]),
array([ 70, 129,  92,   7,  14, 155, 148,  51, 146, 176]))
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
indexing small 0.0072 secs
indexing large 0.0090 secs
(array([ 29, 113,   7,  18, 159, 203,  97,  45]),
array([227, 251,   8, 137,  61, 226, 170,  17]),
array([249,  28, 160,  99,  99, 191, 174, 234]))     
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
non-indexing small 0.0002 secs
non-indexing large 0.0206 secs
```

Comment: I think you should create the list of `True` that you randomly sample only once and hand it to the function, not at every call of `pick_true`. Furthermore, `pick_true_2` doesn't always deliver `n` values, so the timing comparison is not fair. You should make it recursive or use a `while` loop until you find a `True`, in my opinion.

Comment: @StefanS _"I think you should create the list of True ... only once"_ That's what the `n` parameter is for. _"pick_true_2 doesn't always deliver n values"_ Actually, it hardly ever does. However, the expected value is `n` up to roundoff. _"make it recursive or use a while loop until you find a True"_ is not advisable, since just drawing more and discarding excess hits in vectorised code will be significantly faster under almost any circumstances. For moderately large `n` a small safety margin will be sufficient to guarantee enough hits with very high probability.

Comment: I concede the first point for this toy example (no one writes a two line function to call it only once), but "guarantee enough hits with very high probability" sounds like a bug waiting to happen. You are probably right about the "discarding excess" though, so you'd only need a wrapper around the function (or a check afterwards) whether or not you really have enough. Your timing test still drew not enough though, so my original point stands in my opinion.

Comment: @StefanS The point of this whole exercise is not to write a turn-key solution but to demonstrate and roughly quantify the main trade-off, "is it worth-while creating an index or not? what could be a fast implementation of either strategy?" Obviously in production code one would include all sorts of checks but not in proof-of-principle code where it would only distract from what's important. _"whether or not you really have enough"_ You don't really expect anyone with a modicum of common sense to overlook this kind of trivial check, do you?